# Multiple authentication methods working as OR instead of AND in .NET Framework 4.8 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, authentication

I have a Web api in FW 4.8. I currently have it rigged with 2 authentication methods: Salesforce auth and Basic auth. Some of the controllers require Salesforce, some require basic auth, but so far they have worked independently.

As per a new requirement from the client, we need to keep those auth methods exactly as they are, but we need to add a new one: [Okta authentication](https://github.com/okta/okta-aspnet/blob/master/docs/aspnet4x-webapi.md).

This is the code that I used to add it to the `IAppBuilder`, which will run at startup:

```
public static void AddAuthenticationConfiguration(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOktaWebApi(ApiAuthenticationScheme, new OktaWebApiOptions
        {
            OktaDomain = "https://some.domain.com",
            AuthorizationServerId = "default"
        });
    }
```

So now if I add this to one of my controllers:

```
[Authorize]
    public class SomeController : ApiController
    {
      ...
    }
```

...I'll be able to authenticate using the Okta token.

The problem, however, is that if I do this, my old authentication methods (Salesforce or basic auth) stop working altogether.

What I need to do is make it so Okta starts working in parallel with those auth methods.

So, for example, the controllers that once required only Salesforce Auth, will now require
either Okta **OR** Salesforce, and the ones that required Basic Auth, will **also** be accesible using Okta.

So, in summary, I wish to keep the auth methods that I already have in place, untouched, but make them coexist with Okta.

I know this is somewhat easy to do with .Net Core and up, since it has [multiple authentication schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but sadly I cannot upgrade to Core at the moment.

Is there a way to add multiple authentication schemas to a web api controller in Framework 4.8, that behave as an OR rather than an AND (I think this is the case of chaining together multiple Authentication Filters), or is it not possible?

Some more context: here's how I set up both Okta and Salesforce in my Startup class:

```
var saleforceoption = new SalesforceAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = authSettings.SaleforceClientId,
            ClientSecret = authSettings.SaleforceClientSecret,
            AuthenticationType = "Salesforce",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            Prompt = "login",
            Endpoints =
                new SalesforceAuthenticationOptions.SalesforceAuthenticationEndpoints
                {
                    AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://{authSettings.SalesforceCompanyDomain}/services/oauth2/authorize",
                    TokenEndpoint = $"https://{authSettings.SalesforceCompanyDomain}/services/oauth2/token"
                }
        };
        app.UseSalesforceAuthentication(saleforceoption);

        app.AddAuthenticationConfiguration();
```

As per the controller that uses Basic auth, I registered it with a `IAutofacAuthorizationFilter`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.NET 4.7.2 Multiple Owin Auth Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61261951/asp-net-4-7-2-multiple-owin-auth-providers)

Comment: Yes, I think it may work! Found this detailed implementation: https://code-maze.com/dotnet-multiple-authentication-schemes/, will try it out and report back.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work.